# Can we get who all liked our page post in Facebook using their APIs?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I tried to consume Facebook API which need to get the list of who liked my post in my page. Is there any endpoint available in v15.0 (latest) ?

For Example:
If I have a page named "Restaurant" and i have posted a story on that page's feed as "New restaurant on the way to launch" and peoples are liking that post. I want to retrieve who and all liked that post along with the total count. How is it possible ?

Also a question, if a private account is liking that post in that "Restaurant page", how will it be counted too and can we fetch those details too ?

I have tried with the URL, https://graph.facebook.com/101882636084088/feed to get the page feeds and [https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}_{post-id}/likes](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bpage-id%7D_%7Bpost-id%7D/likes), but I'm not able to fetch likes.

I also tried, [https://graph.facebook.com/{page-id}_{post-id}?fields=likes.summary(true)](https://graph.facebook.com/%7Bpage-id%7D_%7Bpost-id%7D?fields=likes.summary(true)), I'm not getting proper count or who and all liked as response. Have anyone came across this scenario ?

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/likes#limitations

Comment: @CBroe, I have tried whatever mentioned in this link, but i only able to fetch the likes i have given on my own post. I could not get the details of all those who have liked or commented in my post. How can i obtain that ?

Comment: What part about _"Only aggregated counts using total_count with the summary parameter are available for Post likes."_ is unclear?